# Email validation not accepting domains with only two characters

Tags: javascript, validation

I am working with an email validation script and all is well, apart from if a user tries to enter an address with only two characters in the domain such as test@me.com or temp@ip.com

The validation then fires an error,  I have looked through but cant see where this behaviour is being targeted,  the code is below...

```
function validate_youremail()
{
    var isvalidemailflag = 0;
    if(jQuery("#property_mail_email").val() == '')
    {
        isvalidemailflag = 1;
    }else
    if(jQuery("#property_mail_email").val() != '')
    {
        var a = jQuery("#property_mail_email").val();
        var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
        //if it's valid email
        if(filter.test(a)){
            isvalidemailflag = 0;
        }else{
            isvalidemailflag = 1;   
        }
    }
    if(isvalidemailflag)
    {
        youremail.addClass("error");
        youremailInfo.text("Please Enter valid Email Address");
        youremailInfo.addClass("message_error2");
        return false;
    }else
    {
        youremail.removeClass("error");
        youremailInfo.text("");
        youremailInfo.removeClass("message_error");
        return true;
    }
```

Its probably staring me straight in the face but its been a long day :)  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Check this out http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Answer (score 2):

```
@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

Means "@" then "one or more of those characters" then "one or more of those characters and dots and hyphens" then "one or more of those characters".

That makes it "at least three characters".

You probably want to change the middle part (of that snippet) to be zero or more (i.e. `*` instead of `+`).

The expression is still broken though. The problem that jumps out at me is that it rejects email addresses with a `+` in the part before the `@`.

Answer (score 1):

Email Validation as per RFC2822 standards.

Pattern: `/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/g`

Source: [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2rhq7)

Mind you, the RFC2822 standard doesn't allow upper case characters in an email address, but you can easily adapt it for your own purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use another regular expression.

This regular expression has been extracted from the [PHP source code written in C.](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/filter/logical_filters.c?revision=321634&view=markup)

```
/^(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22))(?:\.(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-+[a-z0-9]+)*\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-+[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\]))$/i
.test('temp@ip.com');
```